# Why window.open not working to open a phone call link?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Here is my full code,

```
    <div data-ng-repeat="cont in contacts  | filter: searchText">
 <h4 class="contacts" style="border-bottom: none;">{{cont._id}}</h4>
 <ul>
      <li data-ng-repeat="c in cont.subgroup" class="contacts">
       <div class="contact_person">
         <img ng-src="https://127.0.0.1/uploads/pp/{{c.empic}}" onerror="this.src='https://hive.robi.com.bd/uploads/logo.png'" />
         <div class="contact_info info">
             <p class="contInfo">{{c.name}}</p>
             <p class="contInfo">{{c.contact}}</p>
             <p class="contInfo">{{c.email}}</p>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="call">

    <a onclick="window.open('tel:+{{c.contact}}')"><img src="img/call.png"                  id="callImg"></a>

         </div>         
         </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

In `<a onclick="window.open('tel:+{{c.contact}}')"><img src="img/call.png"                  id="callImg"></a>`

it opens new tab and calls tell:+{{c.contact}} but why {{c.contact}} is not getting the value , like a phone number?

> N.B. I tried  `ng-click, ng-href, href` nothing works.

Comment: could you show us your angular code as well? And is this in a `ng-repeat`? Please provide us with more information regarding this piece of HTML.

Comment: I have add my full code @Jorrex

Comment: Could you show us your controller code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I said i tried `ng-href, ng-click` in my question . Yes `ng-href` is correct but I found that the problem was something else.

There was a code snippet in my controller

```
.config(function($provide, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider, $ionicConfigProvider, $compileProvider) {

 $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(http?|ftp|mailto|file|tel|ghttps?|ms-appx|x-wmapp0):/);
  ....
  ....
  // more codes
 }
```

In `$compileProvider`i found that `|tel|` was missing, so after adding this the issue got fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ng-click`. not `onclick`, to use angular `{{}}` syntax... :-)

I.e.:

```
<a ng-click="window.open('tel:'{{c.contact}})">...</a>
```

Or, yet better (as from @Martin's answer), `ng-href`:

```
<a ng-href="tel:{{c.contact}}">...</a>
```

Comment: Right, sorry... @NahiduzzamanRose: can you please elaborate "*I tried ng-click, ng-href, href nothing works*" ?

Answer (score 0):

Click **Run code snippet** below to see a working example.

Why not just use `ng-href`?

```js
function ContactController() {
  this.contact = "+1-312-555-0963"; 
}

angular.module('app', []).controller('ContactController', ContactController);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ContactController as c">
    
    <a ng-href="tel:{{c.contact}}">
        <img src="img/call.png"  alt="Dial {{c.contact}}" />
    </a>
  
</div>
```

Your mobile device browser will see that the protocol of the link is `tel:` and open the dialer application with the provided phone number.